# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects

Tags: python

What is wrong with this code?

```
def welcome(name):
    print "congrats! You created your first Python bank account"+ name


print "Hello welcome to the Python bank Account"
print"To begin please enter your name"
name=raw_input
welcome(name)
```

Comment: Was this intended to be a quiz for us? Otherwise, you would have provided us with what you expected and what you were actually getting...

Comment: It doesn't create a _real_ bank account

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input()` is a function, so you must call it to make it work, and it also accepts an optional argument which is printed when it is invoked:

```
name=raw_input("To begin please enter your name")
```

example:

```
In [61]: name=raw_input("enter your name")
enter your name foo bar

In [62]: name
Out[62]: ' foo bar'
```

Doing just `name=raw_input` simply creates a new reference to `raw_input`, so 
you were actually trying to concatenate a string and `raw_input` in your function 
`welcome` which raised the error:

```
In [63]: name=raw_input

In [64]: name
Out[64]: <function raw_input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `raw_input`.

`raw_input` is a function and you have to call the function for it to return a string, otherwise it returns a function object.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
name = raw_input()
```

raw input is a function and when you want to call you should use () 
for example:

```
>>> s = raw_input('--> ')
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus
>>> s
"Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input